# unable to acaess the application in localhost through saucelabs tunnel

Tags: saucelabs

I am using Saucelabs to test my application on Mac, chrome configuration as I am using windows machine.

As per Saucelabs documentation, downloaded the Saucelabs Connect Proxy. Extracted the file and went to bin folder in command line and executed the below command

```
bin/sc -u <sauce_username> -k <sauce_accesskey> -x <sauce_data_center> -i <tunnel_id>
```

I got the message on the command line as "Sauce Connect is up, you may start your tests." Showed one tunnel is active on the SauceLabs my account under tunnel tab.

I started the session by going to Live --> Crossbrowser; selected the tunnel, localhost application url, browser(chrome 90) and Mac-Sierra and Start Session

Opened the application but it didn't show the feature which are on localhost.

Anyone, please help me on this, is there anything wrong i am doing in the proxy connection, because the same is working fine, if i directly open the application url on my windows machine with chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the [sauce labs documentation](https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/cli/sauce-connect-proxy/index.html) itself. The problem i am getting is related to SSL and here the solution.

If you don't want any domains to be SSL re-encrypted, you can specify all with the argument (i.e., -B all or --no-ssl-bump-domains all)

Now when run the below command to start the tunnel it resolve the issue.

```
bin/sc -u <sauce_username> -k <sauce_accesskey> -x <sauce_data_center> -i <tunnel_id> -B all
```